# We use uiSpec4J for unit testing the GUI, what to do with JDK9?

Tags: java, unit-testing, user-interface, java-9

The last [Github](https://github.com/UISpec4J/UISpec4J) commit to UiSpec4J was back in 2015.
Seeing that it doesn't support JDK9 (it has a lot of dependancies on JDK internal API)

I'd like to hear suggestions to alternatives for testing the application through GUI interaction.

Kind regards.

---

**note:** Seeing this kind of questions is prohibited,
may i suggest people with such line of questions to the javahelp-reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool, software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Turing85 Where to go then? The whole Java community is struggling with JDK9 migration. tons of libraries lack JDK9 support. Where would be the right place to seek an answer??

Comment: The developers themself. For your mentioned library, I would check whether the developers are still active and maybe drop them an eMail. Or try [Software  Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Thanks for the reference to that exchange. Doesn't look very active though

Comment: I don't know anything about UiSpec4J and can't tell if it is actively maintained. Have you tried it on JDK 9 to see if it works? Is there a mailing list to ask questions?

Comment: I added the link to the GitHub project. It's silent since 2015. And i ran Jdeps.exe and it relies hugely on JDK internal API's so it will never run on JDK9.

Comment: @Houtman If you find investing time in the library worth the effort, you can fork the library and migrate it to support JDK9. Not sure how do you contact the maintainers for the same though. (Just thinking it loud.)

Comment: I checked its dependancies.. i think its impossible to get it to work. i listed the jdeps output here https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/7qzt4r/we_used_uispec4j_for_module_testing_the_gui_but/

Comment: The jdeps output is interesting, seems that it depends on the undocumented java.awt.peer package which is finally removed in JDK 9.

Comment: will it work on java 8 ? what is best Swing Testing Framework for Swing Application developed in java 8? Does FEST framework  Support ?